# Read a file and display its data and then upload it. : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to read a xls file and display its data onto the client and then if the user selects, upload it to the server.

i have till now tried :

```
 var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
 r = new FileReader();
  r.onloadend = function(e){
    var data = e.target.result; console.log(data);
    //send you binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
  }
   r.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

But now i am getting data as :

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base ....\
```

which is a downloadable file.

```
How can i read the data of a file on the client side using Angularjs and then selectively upload and save it onto the server.
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is working vs what is not.  What have you tried regarding reading the file and transmitting it, I see the code above but is this in an angular context at all?  Do you have this wrapped in a directive?

Comment: yes. It is in a directive/controller.

Comment: The requirement is that I want to read the content of a file on the client side. or the information in DataURL

Comment: A directive is different from a controller, can you show more of the context around the code above or show an example in a plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: There is not much code left apart from this.this is the main code.